# An image that is bounded - attains maximum but does not attain a minimum

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I'm trying to think of a function that is bounded above and attains a maximum and is bounded below but does not attain a minimum. I have an exam coming up and I'm trying to think of possible scenarios for true or false type questions. I thought this may be a good one but I can't think of an example. The function will be discontinuous but that's as much as I can get. I've been pondering over this for quite a while. Any ideas?

Edit: $\ f:(a,b)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If the domain is $(a,b)$ then any sort of "bump" or "tent" will do: the maximum will be attained in the middle where the bump is highest, and the minimum will be approached as $x \to a$ or $x \to b$.

Comment: $f(x) = -(x-{a+b \over 2})^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat I like it!!

Comment: Isn't your question a bit imprecise?
A minimum is always attained. What you may mean is that the function you have in mind has an infimum over a given interval but the infimum should not be attained.

Comment: @zardos Hmmm I’m not too sure a minimum is always attained on any given open interval. Take the function f(x)=x on any open interval. It doesn’t attain a minimum (a maximum either). But I might be using/understanding the term minimum incorrectly. If so, let me know.

Comment: @funmath The image $f(D)$ of a bounded real-valued function $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a least upper bound (called supremum: $\sup_{x \in D}{f}$) and a greatest lower bound (called infimum: $\inf_{x \in D}{f}$).
If, for example, there is an $x_o \in D$ with $f(x_o) = \inf_{x \in D}{f}$, then one can say that $f$ attains its infimum of $D$ and, hence, has a minimum on $D$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x) = e^{-\left(x-\tfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^2}$$

has a maximum of $1$ at $x=\frac{a+b}{2} \in (a, b)$, but no minimum is attained, though it is bounded below by $0$.

More importantly, this function is not discontinuous. It is in fact very not discontinuous (it is infinitely differentiable).

Comment: True. It doesn't necessarily have to be discontinuous... Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x\mapsto \frac 1 {1+x^2}
$$
This has a maximum value at $x=0.$ Its greatest lower bound is $0,$ but it is everywhere positive.

Comment: But if you take any open interval, say (-5,-3) its doesn't attain a maximum right?

Comment: @funmath : Correct. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = \frac{x(1-x)}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$ on $(0,1)$

[image]